# Getting Handles to dynamically created swfloader

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, swfloader, dynamically-generated

How I can change frame of dynamically created swfloader in Flash Builder 4.5? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code?  Are you really trying to access a SWFLoader?  Or do you want to make changes to a SWF loaded by a SWFLoader?

Answer (score 0):

use `swfloader.content` as a `MovieClip` object.

```
(swfloader.content as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(frame_number);
```